# Passing a custom kernel with more than two arguments into `svm.SVC` in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to use a custom kernel that accepts 3 arguments, with the SVM in sk-learn:

```
def k_gaussian(_x1, _x2, _sigma):
    normsq = np.square(np.linalg.norm(_x1-_x2))
    return np.exp(- normsq/(2 * np.square(sigma)))
```

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#custom-kernels), a custom kernel must only have two arguments, which the `svm.SVC` class will handle automatically with the given input data. We are told to pass the custom kernel in a form like:

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel=my_kernel)
```

However, I'm working on an assignment which requires us to run experiments on SVM performance with varying values of `_sigma`.

How can I achieve that in this case? Can I pass in something like?:

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel=k_gaussian(_sigma=2))
```

Would things like decorators help me here?

Comment: [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) would help. In python this is done through [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Answer (score 7):

That can be done with a closure like:

#### Code:

```
def build_k_gaussian(sigma):

    def k_gaussian(_x1, _x2):
        diff = _x1[:, np.newaxis] - _x2
        normsq = np.square(np.linalg.norm(diff, axis = 2))
        return np.exp(- normsq / (2 * np.square(sigma)))

    return k_gaussian

clf = svm.SVC(kernel=build_k_gaussian(sigma=2))
```

#### How does this work?

The function `k_gaussian` is defined when `build_k_gaussian()` is called.  `k_gaussian` will be able to access the value of `sigma` from when the function was created.  This is known as a closure.

So in the end, `build_k_gaussian` returns a function that takes two parameters, which is what the `kernel` parameter required.

According to the [Using Python functions as kernels on scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#using-python-functions-as-kernels):

> Your kernel must take as arguments two matrices of shape (n_samples_1, n_features), (n_samples_2, n_features) and **return a kernel matrix of shape (n_samples_1, n_samples_2).**

So you need to apply the kernel function on all pairs of samples, therefore 
`diff` broadcasts the `_x1` matrix and subtracts all samples in `_x2` from all samples in `_x1`. You have to calculate the norm along `axis=2`.